# Range Issue With Data Validation

Tags: excel, vba

This Sub attempts to validate data with a drop down list (trying to prevent new inputs from getting entered incorrectly example: names getting spelt wrong)

```
    Sub Project_Managment_Validations()

Dim ws As Worksheet
 Set ws = ActiveSheet

Dim i As Integer
Dim n As Integer

 
 For i = 1 To n
 n = Range("d3").End(xlDown).Count
 

 'Drop Down List for colum C project planner options
With ws.Range(("C3"), ws.Range("C3").End(xlDown)).Validation
.Delete
.Add Type:=xlValidateList, _
Formula1:="R. Catignani,Creutz"             'Final goal would be to have this be a refernce to a range where user can adjust the
                                                                'Options from the worksheet not developer tab.

End With

'Drop Down List for colum D Architct options
 
With ws.Range("D3").Offset((i - 1), 0).Validation
.Delete
.Add Type:=xlValidateList, _
Formula1:="Quinlan,Vachon,Herzog,Peccini,N/A"
End With
Next i

 'Drop Down List for colum E Project Manager options
 
With ws.Range("E3").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Validation
.Delete
.Add Type:=xlValidateList, _
Formula1:="Walsh,B. Catigani,Creutz,Logan,Sorbo, N/A"
End With

'Drop Down List for colum F Superintendent options
 
With ws.Range("F3").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Validation
.Delete
.Add Type:=xlValidateList, _
Formula1:="Sisco,Siciliano,Perry,Asiaf,DeStefano,Jordan, N/A"
End With


End Sub
```

the code works but only adds the drop down list for the last cell not the prior cells.

This confuses me because my understanding of my range object is reading from cell C3-last cell in column C3

Can anyone explain how I'm misunderstanding this range object?

Comment: What do you get from `Debug.Print ws.Range(("C3"), ws.Range("C3").End(xlDown)).Address` ?

Comment: `For i = 1 To n`... why do you have a loop?

Comment: Tim- "Compile error: Expected: expression" this is the error i get when putting the range into the immediate window.

Comment: BigBen I have the loop for reference to other object later in the code I will edit the original post to include rest of the code.

Comment: You'd need to add the Debug.Print line in your code and run it...

Comment: You're setting n inside the loop - you should have that line *before* the loop

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach, using a utility Sub to add the validation

```vb
Sub Project_Managment_Validations()

    With ActiveSheet.Rows(3).Resize(50) ' for example
        AddList .Columns("C"), "R. Catignani,Creutz"
        AddList .Columns("D"), "Quinlan,Vachon,Herzog,Peccini,N/A"
        AddList .Columns("E"), "Walsh,B. Catigani,Creutz,Logan,Sorbo, N/A"
        AddList .Columns("F"), "Sisco,Siciliano,Perry,Asiaf,DeStefano,Jordan, N/A"
    End With
 
End Sub

'add a validation list to `rng` using `lst` as the source
Sub AddList(rng As Range, lst)
    With rng.Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, Formula1:=lst
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello Tim Thank you for your help on this issue you're truly an hero.

Comment: This might be a simple question, I'm using the subs in combination with a larger program.  When I add the call command for the list sub "add list" there is a compile error "argument not optional". Also where is the object rng being defined is the lst the range perimeters?

Comment: When you call `AddList` you must pass in two arguments - a Range, and the list to be added to that range.